# WSO2 ESB - Consume a OAuth2 Service

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-esb

I'm tying to call an OAuth token service to retrieve the token.
Below is my proxy. This is a simple rest endpoint call which retrieves the token. For testing purpose I'm trying to log the token in the response.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="sla_proxy_svc_vo2" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="msg" value="*****INITIATING*****" />
        </log>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"
                    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <nstxt:text xmlns:nstxt="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">grant_type=client_credentials&amp;client_id=G6Dk_3ZdrXOfPiuctufVq6GfTWoa&amp;client_secret=jxA8NTkEClE5xGUvGvvhVTDyXM4a</nstxt:text>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args />
        </payloadFactory>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="msg" value="*****BEFORE TOKEN SERVICE CALL*****" />
        </log>
        <log level="full" />
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
            value="POST" />
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
            value="text/plain" />
        <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
            value="text/plain" />
        <property name="Accept" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
            value="application/json" />
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <http format="rest" method="post" trace="disable"
                    uri-template="http://10.236.70.9:8281/token" />
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="msg" value="******OUT SEQUENCE*******" />
        </log>
        <log level="full" />
        <send />
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence />
</target>
</proxy>
```

I'm getting the below response when I call.

```
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http
```

Will be please if anyone can guide me of I'm doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Hi @Yasothar is your issue fixed, did one of the answer helped you ?

Comment: Yes Nicolas it was helpful. I was able to find it, your answer also helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call the service with the following payload.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <root>
                            <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                            <client_id>G6Dk_3ZdrXOfPiuctufVq6GfTWoa</client_id>
                            <client_secret>jxA8NTkEClE5xGUvGvvhVTDyXM4a</client_secret>
                        </root>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args />
        </payloadFactory>
```

Also had to add the content type as below.

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
```

This worked and retrieved the token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template I'm using in a component to set the oAuth token, you could probably adapt it a bit for your case (sounds like you do not need grantType or user credentials)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template name="getToken" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="tokenURL"/>
    <parameter name="clientId"/>
    <parameter name="clientSecret"/>
    <parameter name="grantType"/>
    <sequence>
        <property description="Base64 crendetials" expression="base64Encode(fn:concat($func:clientId,':',$func:clientSecret))" name="credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property description="Authentication" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', get-property('credentials'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <property expression="$func:tokenURL" name="uri.var.authUrl" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="$func:grantType" name="uri.var.grantType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
                <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.authUrl}?grant_type={uri.var.grantType}"/>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <property expression="json-eval($.access_token)" name="OAuth_Token" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property action="remove" description="Remove Headers" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
        <property description="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ',get-property('OAuth_Token'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    </sequence>
</template>
```